# New Laptop Shaders Failing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So i just got a new alienware 14 laptop. base minecraft works fine on it but as soon as i turn my shaders on it crashes. the error report is down below, anyone have any ideas on how to fix this, i've spent about 2 hours going through all my settings in minecraft itself and i even updated my video drivers jsut to be safe but it's still crashing, thanks in advance

```
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 7.2.211.1121 for Minecraft 1.7.2 loading
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, version 1.7.0_67, running on Windows 8.1:x86:6.3, installed at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [FML]: Loading tweaker shadersmodcore.loading.SMCTweaker from ShadersModCore-v2.3.12-mc1.7.2-f1040.jar
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name shadersmodcore.loading.SMCTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker
[17:17:42] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[17:17:43] [main/INFO] [FML]: Found valid fingerprint for Minecraft Forge. Certificate fingerprint e3c3d50c7c986df74c645c0ac54639741c90a557
[17:17:43] [main/INFO] [FML]: Found valid fingerprint for Minecraft. Certificate fingerprint cd99959656f753dc28d863b46769f7f8fbaefcfc
[17:17:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.CoreModManager$FMLPluginWrapper
[17:17:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker
[17:17:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class shadersmodcore.loading.SMCTweaker
[17:17:43] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
[SMC FNE]transforming azd net.minecraft.client.Minecraft
[SMC FNE] 65414 (+59)
[17:17:44] [main/INFO]: Setting user: KoshkaBearr
[SMC FNE]transforming ahu net.minecraft.block.Block
[SMC FNE] 68932 (+0)
[SMC FNE]transforming zt net.minecraft.item.ItemBlock
[SMC FNE] 6395 (+0)
[17:17:45] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.0
[SMC FNE]transforming bul net.minecraft.client.renderer.OpenGlHelper
[SMC FNT]    set activeTexUnit
[SMC FNE] 3295 (+65)
[SMC FNE]transforming bpi net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.DynamicTexture
[SMC FNE] 1328 (+234)
[SMC FNE]transforming bph net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.AbstractTexture
[SMC FNE] 1028 (+376)
[SMC FNE]transforming bpz net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.ITextureObject
[SMC FNE] 297 (+63)
[SMC FNE]transforming bpr net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap
[SMC FNT]    loadRes
[SMC FNT]    loadRes
[SMC FNT]    allocateTextureMap
[SMC FNT]    setSprite setIconName
[SMC FNT]    uploadTexSubForLoadAtlas
[SMC FNE] 15888 (+765)
[SMC FNE]transforming bng net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.Render
[SMC FNR]    conditionally skip default shadow
[SMC FNE] 9451 (+78)
[SMC FNE]transforming ble net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderBlocks
[SMC FNE] 151889 (+388)
[17:17:45] [Client thread/INFO] [MinecraftForge]: Attempting early MinecraftForge initialization
[17:17:45] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: MinecraftForge v10.12.2.1121 Initialized
[17:17:45] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Replaced 182 ore recipies
[17:17:45] [Client thread/INFO] [MinecraftForge]: Completed early MinecraftForge initialization
[17:17:46] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Searching C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods for mods
[17:17:46] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Also searching C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods\1.7.2 for mods
[17:17:47] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader has identified 3 mods to load
[17:17:48] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, FMLFileResourcePack:Forge Mod Loader, FMLFileResourcePack:Minecraft Forge, JohnSmithLegacy_3.zip
[17:17:48] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Processing ObjectHolder annotations
[17:17:48] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Found 341 ObjectHolder annotations
[17:17:48] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Configured a dormant chunk cache size of 0
[17:17:48] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Applying holder lookups
[17:17:48] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Holder lookups applied
[SMC FNE]transforming bpx net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager
[SMC FNE] 5662 (+117)

Starting up SoundSystem...
[SMC FNE]transforming bpm net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.SimpleTexture
[SMC FNR]    loadSimpleTexture
[SMC FNE] 2642 (+301)
[SMC FNE]transforming blz net.minecraft.client.renderer.Tessellator
[SMC FNE] 8282 (-731)
Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
    (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://
OpenAL initialized.

[17:17:48] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[SMC FNE]transforming bon net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderSpider
[SMC FNE] 2157 (+66)
[SMC FNE]transforming bnz net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RendererLivingEntity
[SMC FNE] 15374 (+349)
[SMC FNE]transforming bir net.minecraft.client.model.ModelRenderer
[SMC FNE] 6336 (+0)
[SMC FNE]transforming bne net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderEnderman
[SMC FNE] 4174 (+66)
[SMC FNE]transforming bnd net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.RenderDragon
[SMC FNE] 7059 (+66)
[SMC FNE]transforming blq net.minecraft.client.renderer.ItemRenderer
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/ItemRenderer.func_78443_a(Lnet/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase;Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;I)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/ItemRenderer.renderItem(Lnet/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase;Lnet/minecraft/item/ItemStack;ILnet/minecraftforge/client/IItemRenderer$ItemRenderType;)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/ItemRenderer.func_78441_a()V
[SMC FNE] 19145 (+68)
[SMC FNE]transforming bll net.minecraft.client.renderer.EntityRenderer
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78476_b(FI)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78483_a(D)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78463_b(D)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78471_a(FJ)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_82829_a(Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderGlobal;F)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78466_h(F)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78468_a(IF)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/EntityRenderer.func_78469_a(FFFF)Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer;
[SMC FNE] 47265 (+1577)
ShadersMod version 2.3.12
[Shaders] Loading configuration.
[Shaders] Loaded shaderpack.
[SMC FNE]transforming bls net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderGlobal
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderGlobal.func_147589_a(Lnet/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase;Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/culling/ICamera;F)V
[SMC FNT]    beginEntities
[SMC FNT]    endEntities
[SMC FNT]    beginTileEntities
[SMC FNT]    endTileEntities
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderGlobal.func_72719_a(Lnet/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase;ID)I
[SMC FNT]    disableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    disableFog
[SMC FNT]    enableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    enableFog
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderGlobal.func_72714_a(F)V
[SMC FNT]    disableFog
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 0
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 0
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 0
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 0
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 0
[SMC FNT]    enableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    disableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    enableFog
[SMC FNT]    disableFog
[SMC FNT]    disableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 2
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 2
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 2
[SMC FNT]    enableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 3
[SMC FNT]    preCelestialRotate
[SMC FNT]    *glRotatef 4
[SMC FNT]    postCelestialRotate
[SMC FNT]    disableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    enableFog
[SMC FNT]    disableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    enableTexture2D
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderGlobal.func_72717_a(Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/Tessellator;Lnet/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer;F)V
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderGlobal.drawBlockDamageTexture(Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/Tessellator;Lnet/minecraft/entity/EntityLivingBase;F)V
[SMC FNT]    beginBlockDestroyProgress
[SMC FNT]    endBlockDestroyProgress
[SMC FNR]  patch method net/minecraft/client/renderer/RenderGlobal.func_72731_b(Lnet/minecraft/entity/player/EntityPlayer;Lnet/minecraft/util/MovingObjectPosition;IF)V
[SMC FNT]    disableTexture2D
[SMC FNT]    enableTexture2D
[SMC FNE] 59764 (+570)
[SMC FNE]transforming bpv net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite
[SMC FNE] 10907 (+63)
[17:17:55] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures/blocks-atlas
allocateTextureMap 0 4 1024 512 1.0 
[SMC FNE]transforming bqe net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureCompass
[SMC FNE] 2550 (+63)
[SMC FNE]transforming bqd net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureClock
[SMC FNE] 1885 (+63)
[17:17:55] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 512x512 textures/items-atlas
allocateTextureMap 1 0 512 512 1.0 
[17:17:55] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader has successfully loaded 3 mods
[17:17:55] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default, FMLFileResourcePack:Forge Mod Loader, FMLFileResourcePack:Minecraft Forge, JohnSmithLegacy_3.zip
[17:17:55] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 512x512 textures/items-atlas
allocateTextureMap 1 0 512 512 1.0 
[17:17:57] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures/blocks-atlas
allocateTextureMap 0 4 1024 512 1.0 

SoundSystem shutting down...
    Author: Paul Lamb,


Starting up SoundSystem...
Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
    (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http:/.lwjgl.org)
OpenAL initialized.

[17:17:59] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[SMC FNE]transforming bbt net.minecraft.client.gui.GuiOptions
[SMC FNT]    decrease language button size
[SMC FNT]    add shaders button
[SMC FNT]    shaders button action
[SMC FNE] 5950 (+158)
[17:18:05] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.7.2
[17:18:05] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[17:18:06] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Injecting existing block and item data into this server instance
[17:18:06] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Applying holder lookups
[17:18:06] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Holder lookups applied
[17:18:06] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Loading dimension 0 (New World) (net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer@11f73a0)
[17:18:06] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Loading dimension 1 (New World) (net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer@11f73a0)
[17:18:06] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: Loading dimension -1 (New World) (net.minecraft.server.integrated.IntegratedServer@11f73a0)
[17:18:06] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id entityPokeChest
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id entityPokeChest
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:06] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id entityPokeChest
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id entityPokeChest
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id entityPokeChest
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing spawn area: 64%
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id entityPokeChest
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id Apricorn Tree
[17:18:07] [Server thread/WARN]: Skipping BlockEntity with id entityPokeChest
[17:18:07] [Netty Client IO #0/INFO] [FML]: Server protocol version 1
[17:18:07] [Netty IO #1/INFO] [FML]: Client protocol version 1
[17:18:07] [Netty IO #1/INFO] [FML]: Client attempting to join with 3 mods : mcp@9.03,FML@7.2.211.1121,Forge@10.12.2.1121
[17:18:07] [Netty IO #1/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [] at CLIENT
[17:18:07] [Netty Client IO #0/INFO] [FML]: Attempting connection with missing mods [] at SERVER
[17:18:08] [Client thread/INFO] [FML]: [Client thread] Client side modded connection established
[17:18:08] [Server thread/INFO] [FML]: [Server thread] Server side modded connection established
[17:18:08] [Server thread/INFO]: KoshkaBearr[local:E:af38738a] logged in with entity id 127 at (128.29023245397713, 70.0, 189.03957262049107)
[17:18:08] [Server thread/INFO]: KoshkaBearr joined the game
[SMC FNE]transforming bpj net.minecraft.client.renderer.ThreadDownloadImageData
[SMC FNE] 3179 (+285)
[Shaders] OpenGL 2.0 = Y    2.1 = Y    3.0 = Y    3.2 = Y
[Shaders] GL_MAX_DRAW_BUFFERS = 8
[Shaders] GL_MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS_EXT = 8
[Shaders] GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS = 32
Program gbuffers_basic loaded
Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_textured.fsh
WARNING: 0:17: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:18: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:32: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:32: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:32: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:32: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Program gbuffers_textured loaded
Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_textured_lit.fsh
WARNING: 0:20: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:20: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:20: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Program gbuffers_textured_lit loaded
Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_terrain.vsh
WARNING: 0:37: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:49: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:49: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:50: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:50: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:59: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:72: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:72: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:73: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:73: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:74: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:74: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:75: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:101: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:117: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:138: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:150: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:150: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:151: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:151: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:152: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:152: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:153: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:157: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:178: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:178: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:179: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:179: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:180: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:180: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:213: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_terrain.fsh
WARNING: 0:9: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:60: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:87: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:125: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:139: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:139: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:141: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:141: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:141: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Program gbuffers_terrain loaded
Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_water.vsh
WARNING: 0:39: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:139: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:139: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:139: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_water.fsh
WARNING: 0:40: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:40: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:40: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:42: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:43: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:56: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:62: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:62: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:62: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:62: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:62: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:68: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:68: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:68: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:68: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:80: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:80: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:80: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Program gbuffers_water loaded
Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_entities.fsh
WARNING: 0:7: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:39: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:40: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:50: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:63: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:63: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:63: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:69: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:69: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Program gbuffers_entities loaded
Info log: /shaders/gbuffers_hand.fsh
WARNING: 0:35: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:35: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:35: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:47: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:54: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float



Program gbuffers_hand loaded
Program gbuffers_weather loaded
Info log: /shaders/composite.vsh
WARNING: 0:35: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:35: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:36: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:36: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:94: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:153: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float


Shadow map resolution: 413
Shadow map half-plane: 61.3
Info log: /shaders/composite.fsh
WARNING: 0:115: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:115: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:122: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:122: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:123: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:123: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:158: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:164: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float
WARNING: 0:175: Only GLSL version > 110 allows postfix "F" or "f" for float

An unrecoverable stack overflow has occurred.
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_STACK_OVERFLOW (0xc00000fd) at pc=0x2c15cea7, pid=6304, tid=1036
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd32.dll+0x3dcea7]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid6304.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is [requesting technical support for modded Minecraft](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/10390/4797). We allow an exception for unmodded or 'Vanilla' Minecraft, please see [How do I ask a good Minecraft Bug/Crash Question?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/9943/4797)

Answer (score 2):

Since the error is reported to occur in `ig75icd32.dll`, which is an Intel graphics driver, you may have an issue similar to "[Minecraft Forge 1.7.10 keeps crashing as soon as I launch the game with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/178772/83655)". Does your laptop have a dedicated 'high performance' GPU installed?  If so, running Minecraft on that GPU may resolve your issues.

If that doesn't work, or you do not have an alternate GPU, you should check for new [drivers for your Intel chip](https://downloadcenter.intel.com).  It may be that newer versions will solve this issue (it looks like the problem is unsupported syntax; later versions may have support for them).

As a last-ditch hail mary, you *could* try increasing the stack size in your profile.  Try adding `-Xss2M` to the JVM arguments, which should set thread stack size to 2MB<sup>(1)</sup>.  I'd be surprised to hear it resolved your issue, though; maybe it needs a little (or a lot) more space, but it seems more likely it's a bug.

<sub>(1) Or, you know, a value greater than this, but defaults are usually less than 1M.  If **doubling** the stack size doesn't work, then tripling probably won't either.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise it at first, but it was running off of the integrated graphics, not my gtx, now i have changed it it's working great, thankyou!

Comment: @Koshka If this answered your question, please click the green checkmark to the left of the post! :)