# Minecraft won't run on my son's new laptop

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I have uninstalled Java and Minecraft, updated the graphics card and even did a system restore back to when the computer was working.  I am trying to make my son happy again with his Minecraft addiction! How can I resolve this?

Below is the error report I keep getting:

```
Jan 07, 2015 10:19:19 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Loading tweak class name optifine.OptiFineTweaker
Jan 07, 2015 10:19:19 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Using primary tweak class name optifine.OptiFineTweaker
Jan 07, 2015 10:19:19 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Calling tweak class optifine.OptiFineTweaker
OptiFineTweaker: acceptOptions
OptiFineTweaker: injectIntoClassLoader skipped, OptiFine is loaded as a library
OptiFineTweaker: getLaunchArguments
OptiFineTweaker: getLaunchTarget
Jan 07, 2015 10:19:20 PM net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LogWrapper log
INFO: Launching wrapped minecraft {net.minecraft.client.main.Main}
[22:19:25] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: yolonerd101
[22:19:25] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:ad65eaeb2df249609d210cd7e4226f97:1da861b98afa4bd7aad2ad85789f5490)
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: atr.func_149713_g
[22:19:30] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.1
[OptiFine] 
[OptiFine] OptiFine_1.8_HD_U_B4
[OptiFine] Wed Jan 07 22:19:31 PST 2015
[OptiFine] OS: Windows 8.1 (amd64) version 6.3
[OptiFine] Java: 1.8.0_25, Oracle Corporation
[OptiFine] VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
[OptiFine] LWJGL: 2.9.1
[OptiFine] OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics, version 4.0.0 - Build 10.18.10.3621, Intel
[OptiFine] OpenGL Version: 4.0
[OptiFine] OpenGL Fancy fog: Not available (GL_NV_fog_distance)
[OptiFine] Maximum texture size: 8192x8192
[OptiFine] Checking for new version
[22:19:31] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[OptiFine] *** Reloading textures ***
[OptiFine] Resource packs: Default
[OptiFine] Version found: B4
[22:19:34] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[22:19:34] [Thread-7/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[22:19:34] [Thread-7/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
AL lib: (EE) MMDevApiOpenPlayback: Device init failed: 0x80004005
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: ModLoader
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraft.src.FMLRenderAccessLibrary
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: LightCache
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: BlockCoord
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.common.ForgeHooks
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.MinecraftForgeClient
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.ForgeHooksClient
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.IItemRenderer$ItemRenderType
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: bgd.getSkyRenderer
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: bgd.getCloudRenderer
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: bgd.getWeatherRenderer
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: aqu.countEntities
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.IRenderHandler
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.common.DimensionManager
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.event.world.WorldEvent$Load
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.event.GuiScreenEvent$DrawScreenEvent$Pre
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.event.GuiScreenEvent$DrawScreenEvent$Post
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityViewRenderEvent$FogColors
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityViewRenderEvent$FogDensity
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.client.event.EntityViewRenderEvent$RenderFogEvent
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.Event$Result
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.event.ForgeEventFactory
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Class not present: net.minecraftforge.event.world.ChunkWatchEvent$UnWatch
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: atr.getBedDirection
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: atr.isBedFoot
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: atr.canRenderInPass
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: atr.hasTileEntity
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: atr.canCreatureSpawn
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Field not present: wv.captureDrops
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Field not present: wv.capturedDrops
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: wv.shouldRenderInPass
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: wv.canRiderInteract
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: bcm.shouldRenderInPass
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: bcm.getRenderBoundingBox
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: alq.onEntitySwing
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: wq.isCurativeItem
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: amj.hasEffect
[OptiFine] (Reflector) Method not pesent: amy.getRecordResource
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/0_glass_white/glass_pane_white.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/0_glass_white/glass_white.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/10_glass_purple/glass_pane_purple.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/10_glass_purple/glass_purple.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/11_glass_blue/glass_blue.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/11_glass_blue/glass_pane_blue.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/12_glass_brown/glass_brown.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/12_glass_brown/glass_pane_brown.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/13_glass_green/glass_green.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/13_glass_green/glass_pane_green.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/14_glass_red/glass_pane_red.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/14_glass_red/glass_red.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/15_glass_black/glass_black.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/15_glass_black/glass_pane_black.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/1_glass_orange/glass_orange.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/1_glass_orange/glass_pane_orange.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/2_glass_magenta/glass_magenta.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/2_glass_magenta/glass_pane_magenta.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/3_glass_light_blue/glass_light_blue.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/3_glass_light_blue/glass_pane_light_blue.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/4_glass_yellow/glass_pane_yellow.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/4_glass_yellow/glass_yellow.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/5_glass_lime/glass_lime.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/5_glass_lime/glass_pane_lime.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/6_glass_pink/glass_pane_pink.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/6_glass_pink/glass_pink.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/7_glass_gray/glass_gray.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/7_glass_gray/glass_pane_gray.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/8_glass_silver/glass_pane_silver.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/8_glass_silver/glass_silver.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/9_glass_cyan/glass_cyan.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/9_glass_cyan/glass_pane_cyan.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/bookshelf.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/glass.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/glasspane.properties
[OptiFine] ConnectedTextures: mcpatcher/ctm/default/sandstone.properties
[OptiFine] Multipass connected textures: false
[22:19:41] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[OptiFine] *** Reloading custom textures ***
[OptiFine] Loading custom colors: textures/colormap/grass.png
[OptiFine] Loading custom colors: textures/colormap/foliage.png
[22:19:43] [Thread-7/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[22:19:43] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[22:20:03] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to mcbrawl.com, 25565
[22:20:09] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                          
[22:20:09] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Connected to MCBrawl Lobby #9
[22:20:09] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] 
[22:20:09] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] You haven't voted today!
[22:20:09] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Click §nhere to earn rewards.
[22:20:09] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] 
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000001a81561c, pid=5180, tid=5652
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x17561c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\mathman225\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid5180.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

Comment: The output here says it has a more detailed log located at C:\Users\mathman225\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid5180.log.  Linking to a dump of that log may help us help you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Comment: Possible solution here: [Is there a list of error codes for Minecraft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/203664/4797)

Answer (score 17):

You son has installed some Minecraft mods, one of which is broken and crashing Minecraft. It's hard to tell which mod because it appears to be crashing the game before its name is mentioned in the log.

However, there is one clue: there are errors that indicate something is looking for "Forge" and not finding it. Forge is a mod that does nothing visible by itself, but provides services that other mods can use. Many mods use Forge, and won't work without it being installed first. The culprit mod is most likely a mod that requires Forge. Mods that require Forge will say so in their installation instructions — which means your son installed something without reading and following the necessary instructions.

The solution is to ask your son to remove the culprit mod. He might be able to figure out which one it is by reading through the install instructions for each mod he has installed. The culprit mod will say clearly somewhere in its documentation that Forge is required by the mod.

If he's unable to figure it out by investigating documentation, the next solution is to remove mods one by one until the game starts working again.

An alternative is to restore Minecraft to its unmodded state by going to `C:\Users\[your son's Windows laptop username]\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft`, finding the `versions` folder, and deleting it. Deleting *only* the `versions` folder will make Minecraft reinstall itself next time it is run, but will leave all your son's save-games (or "worlds") intact.

(Note that installing mods is a legitimate thing to do and not cause for alarm. Mods are generally benign, usually adding new features created by the community of players. However, when someone takes it upon themselves to start adding mods to the game, they are also preventing anyone else from helping them fix the problem if it goes wrong — so it's their responsibility to learn how to install and troubleshoot mods themselves. Mods are also created by the community, not Mojang, so they carry no guarantees that they work properly.)

Comment: Looks like he has a forge dependent mod, without having forge.
(But that seems unlikely, since forge is so common as a dependency, so i must be reading it wrong)

Comment: @Oxinabox No, I think you're right. There are traces of non-Forge modding going on (e.g., Optifine, mcpatcher), but all those missing-function errors and the lack of the usual Forge startup messages probably means a Forge mod is installed without Forge.

Comment: Wouldn't it also be fair to offer as an alternative installing Forge (or telling the son, whatever age he might be, to install Forge, since he clearly is mod-capable and probably just overlooked the requirement)?

Comment: @gatherer818 Maaaybe. I know that Optifine and Forge don't get along in every version of each, and even compatible versions have to be installed in a specific order. MCPatcher, being a self-installing mod in the "old style" of directly hacking the .jar, may or may not work with Forge or may only work if things are done in a certain order, and I don't know because I haven't touched MCPatcher in years. That kind of advice is beyond what I can provide here and is liable to change over time. Someone else tackling it may be helpful.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I used to mod MC extensively but have gotten lazy (and tired of every update breaking my mods and thus making worlds unplayable until and unless every mod author updated, and then having to reinstall all of them) so I haven't personally modded in quite a while, instead using modpacks (go go Technic Patcher!), so I didn't realize.  Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @gatherer818 I feel the same, and though I've hand-made modpacks before, it's a drag that gets old quick when versions change. Very much looking forward to a day when mods are directly supported and it becomes easier — and the kind of problem in this question stops happening.

Answer (score 3):

While [SevenSidedDie's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/200984/83655) addresses a probable future issue, this stood out to me in the JVM crash log:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at (snip)

Problematic frame:
C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x17561c]
```

Your JVM dies in a native code, more specifically, Intel graphics device driver code (`ig7icd64.dll`).  This makes me think the immediate problem is similar to: [New Laptop Shaders Failing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/182364/83655).

If you have another GPU in your computer, try running Minecraft with that, as per: right mouse button on the executable → Run With → (something other than "integrated"). Dedicated GPUs tend to have better supported/more compatible drivers than integrated ones.

> [OptiFine] OpenGL: Intel(R) HD Graphics, version 4.0.0 - **Build 10.18.10.3621**, Intel

From looking at your device drivers and comparing them with the drivers on [Intel's download center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=24593&lang=eng&ProdId=3711), I'm thinking they may be out of date, but it's hard to tell without knowing the actual processor type.  You said you updated your graphics drivers; did you check for your integrated graphics?

Comment: Ah, good catch. Actually, it's probably just the familiar "Java 8 hates Minecraft" problem that is fixed by removing Java 8 and installing Java 7. (Java 7 had the same problem when it was new.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Considering the nature of this particular crash, I find it unlikely the JVM version is involved.  If downgrading does help resolve this issue, well, I'd definitely consider researching it.

Answer (score -2):

It's not mods, he just has the new java update 1.8.0_25. Minecraft doesn't support that. You should uninstall java 1.8.0_25 and reinstall java 1.7.0_25 if you get the following:

```
[16:27:29] [main/ERROR] [LaunchWrapper]: Unable to launch
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    **at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]**
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:117) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]
```

Answer (score -3):

Allright, first things first. Minecraft itself has no problems with java 1.8, but forge does. so try to find a java 1.7 (comes with the old RE7 instead of RE8, this might cause very new programs to not work but it probebly won't).

if that does not work you might be dealing with a RAM problem. to solve this you want to alocate more RAM to minecraft. You can do this in the profile editor under Java settings (advanced). In JVM Arguments you will see that you can input how much ram you want Minecraft to be running on. In this box you fill in:

> "-Xmx2048M -Xms2048M" for 2GB ram
>
> "-Xmx4096M -Xms4096M" for 4GB ram

To add more, add 1024 to the numbers for an extra gigabyte.

> eg, 4096 (4GB) + 1024 = 5120 (5GB)

(Remember you need to make sure other programs can still run without Minecraft consuming all the ram so that might be a problem)

If that does not help, try deleting your .minecraft folder in it's respective location.

> Mac: /Library/minecraft
>
> Windows: Press Windows+R, type %appdata& and press Enter. Then locate .minecraft.

**But make sure you back the folder up!**

Many people have used this technique for similar problems without: eg. Internet connection, so the launcher could not re-download the folder. This is also the folder were world saves and texture-packs are stored so again, **back it up first.**