# My minecraft keeps crashing after about 25 seconds of running

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

My Minecraft keeps crashing after a couple seconds of running. I've read online about this issue and can't find anything. It says this after the crash.

```
[12:24:13] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: nkoak28
[12:24:13] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is token:73f4a663d7d6417e96cee15634624bbf:d329cba1538248ba85a724c1ddbe7098)
[12:24:14] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[12:24:15] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[12:24:16] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[12:24:16] [Thread-6/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[12:24:16] [Thread-6/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[12:24:16] [Thread-6/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[12:24:17] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[12:24:18] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 512x512 textures-atlas
[12:24:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Starting integrated minecraft server version 1.8.8
[12:24:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Generating keypair
[12:24:31] [Server thread/INFO]: Preparing start region for level 0
[12:24:33] [Server thread/INFO]: Changing view distance to 12, from 10
[12:24:33] [Server thread/INFO]: nkoak28[local:E:5442333b] logged in with entity id 339 at (-120.06118661740985, 68.0, 270.1459368633843)
[12:24:33] [Server thread/INFO]: nkoak28 joined the game
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007fffd6c7d5d3, pid=7808, tid=5780
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig7icd64.dll+0x6d5d3]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7808.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: While it's most likely not going to be fixed here, can you copy/paste the log in C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid7808.log ?

Comment: ... I'm sure this error has been asked about a hundred times before. Oh wait... [It](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191360/minecraft-crashes-with-exception-access-violation-0xc0000005) [has been](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/205643/exception-access-violation-0xc0000005) [asked](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178772/minecraft-forge-1-7-10-keeps-crashing-as-soon-as-i-launch-the-game) [that](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191360/minecraft-crashes-with-exception-access-violation-0xc0000005/201727?s=5|0.5506#201727) many times. :/ (Ran out of characters

Comment: ... I vote for this question to be closed as a duplicate of [this really long search results containing tonnes of duplicates of the **same question**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION+%280xc0000005%29)

Comment: @aytimothy, it is a lot more useful to link the original question. What you have linked is a list of exact same questions; half of which are *not* marked as duplicates. You cant have a duplicate where there is an array of original questions.

Comment: 2wow your right. it didn't.. anyway, I have renamed the original to include the error code in its title. Fixes all the confusion

Answer (score 2):

I heard that using Java 7 fixes this problem. Give it a shot maybe? You can also decrease the amount of RAM given to Minecraft. Although I don't have the time to provide the information on how-to. Just hoping I shove you on the right track. Good luck.

Comment: this wasn't the problem but it will definitely prevent future problems so Thank you, Before i was using java 8, and i guess it's not all the reliable yet.

Answer (score -1):

Hold the <kbd>windows</kbd> key and press `R`, then run `%appdata%\.minecraft` and delete everything within that folder. Then try again.

If that doesn't work, uninstall current version of java, download the ORIGINAL minecraft launcher and install the latest java.

## Remember to back up your saves and resource packs

Comment: If you choose to do this, I recommend backing up \saves and whatever else you wish to keep.

Comment: Thank you It worked, I deleted the whole thing actually, uninstalled java and the whole .minecraft folder itself, then reinstalled everything and it's back to normal so thank you VERY much